# Error wait with function already contains async

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

I have this error: await is only valid in async function

My code:

```
    async function solve(){
                var requestUrl = "url";

                $.ajax({url: "requestUrl", success: function(result){
                    if(result.length < 3){
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        if(result.substring(0, 3) == "OK|"){
                            var ID = result.substring(3);

                            for(var i=0; i<24; i++){
                                var ansUrl = "url"+ID;  

                                $.ajax({url: "ansUrl", success: function(ansresult){
                                        if(ansresult.length < 3){
                                            return ansresult;
                                        }else{
                                            if(ansresult.substring(0, 3) == "OK|"){
                                                return ansresult;
                                            }else if (ansresult != "ERROR"){
                                                return ansresult;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                                 await sleep(5000); // <-- ERROR
                            }

                        }else{
                            return ansresult;   
                        }
                    }
                },
                fail: function(){
                    return "";
                    }
                });

            }
 solve();
```

The function had no async, I put it in the beginning and still it still gives this error. 
I do not know if it's a problem in ajax

Comment: What do you expect that `await` to do for you? What does `sleep()` look like?

Comment: @Pointy probably just a [generic `sleep` call](https://jsbin.com/divine-water-FE0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to use the `await` keyword in the `success` callback of that ajax call, not in the `async function solve`. Do not use `success` and `fail` callbacks when working with promises (implied by working with `async`/`await`)!

Instead, use the promise that `$.ajax` already returns, `await` it, and write your code without that much nesting:

```
async function solve() {
    try {
        const requestUrl = "url";
        const result = await $.ajax({url: requestUrl});
//                     ^^^^^
        if (result.length < 3) {
            return false;
        } else if (result.substring(0, 3) == "OK|") {
            const ID = result.substring(3);
            for (let i=0; i<24; i++){
                const ansUrl = "url"+ID;  
                const ansresult = await $.ajax({url: ansUrl});
//                                ^^^^^
                if (ansresult.length < 3) {
                    return ansresult;
                } else if(ansresult.substring(0, 3) == "OK|") {
                    return ansresult;
                } else if (ansresult != "ERROR") {
                    return ansresult;
                }
                await sleep(5000); // works here!
            }
        } else {
            return ansresult; // not in scope?!
        }
    } catch(e) {
        return "";
    }
}
solve().then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the outermost ajax call to look like this:

`success: async function(result)`

You're using `await` inside that inner function which is not `async`

Comment: That will clear up the syntax error, but the code still won't work; `$.ajax()` is not going to pay attention to the returned Promise.

Answer (score 0):

The function in which you use the `await` keyword must be an async function - You've just made the parent function async.

In ajax callbacks, just change `success: function(` to `success: async function(`